# incompatible ellipsis match counts for template

Tags: functional-programming, racket

I am trying to work on writing objects with Racket, and I am trying to implement "inheritance".

```
(define-syntax class-trait
  (syntax-rules (with)
    [(class <Class> (<attr> ...) (with <traits> ...)
       [(<method> <param> ...) <body>]...)
       (define (<Class> <attr> ...)
         (lambda (msg)
           (cond [(equal? msg (id->string <attr>)) <attr>]
                 ...
                 [(equal? msg (id->string <method>))
                  (lambda (<param> ...) <body>)]
                 ...
                 [else ((<traits> <param> ...) ... msg)]
                 ))
     )]))
```

This is what I have currently, but for the final else statement, the ellipsis does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's first discuss the meaning of the error: "incompatible ellipsis match counts for template".

Suppose the `a` matches `(1 x #t)` and `b` matches `(2 y #f)`, then
the template `((a b) ...)` produces `((1 2) (x y) (# f)`.

Now if `a` matches `(1 x)` and `b` matches `(2 y #f)` then what should `((a b) ...)` produce ? The match counts of `a` and `b` are not compatible (of the same length).

In your code, I think, the template

```
 ((<traits> <param> ...) ...
```

could be problematic, if the number of `<traits>` doesn't match the number of `<param> ...`s.

Comment: I was also thinking about doing it this way. [else ((<traits> <param> ...) msg) ...]  so that the ellipsis of traits is repeated the number of times outside of the template.